# Pairwise Angle Calculation of Complex Vector

Tags: matlab, geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have a complex vector (cv) as follows:

```
743.000000000000 + 1150.00000000000i
744.000000000000 + 1147.00000000000i
745.000000000000 + 1146.00000000000i
746.000000000000 + 1144.00000000000i
748.000000000000 + 1145.00000000000i
751.000000000000 + 1145.00000000000i
756.000000000000 + 1145.00000000000i
760.000000000000 + 1144.00000000000i
765.000000000000 + 1144.00000000000i
769.000000000000 + 1143.00000000000i
773.000000000000 + 1142.00000000000i
776.000000000000 + 1142.00000000000i
778.000000000000 + 1142.00000000000i
780.000000000000 + 1141.00000000000i
781.000000000000 + 1141.00000000000i
```

These are XY coordinates plotted in 2D space and I want to calculate the pairwise angle between each of the successive elements in the vector, e.g. angle between element 1 and element 2, between element 2 and element 3, etc. I have tried calculating it with atan2(imag(cv),real(cv)) and angle(cv), however the radian values I obtain don't appear correct, as they should be much closer to 1.57/90 degrees:

```
0.997176848026074
0.995371676259612
0.994359765918558
0.992947720321641
0.992122189213936
0.990288012755825
0.987240833611188
0.984409230727208
0.981383002699897
0.978565844271060
0.975754418763486
0.973955062297999
0.972757930118131
0.971154674293130
0.970557623825132
```

How can I best calculate the pairwise angles between these coordinates?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: In any case, you are getting `1-1.57/90` in your results.

Comment: Very similar to @Stewie Griffin answer, but you could also use: `ang = atand(diff(imag(cv))./diff(real(cv)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, you want the angle between row 1 and 2, row 2 and 3 and so on. To get this, you can calculate the difference (`diff`) between each row, then use `angle` to get the angles between each element:

```
cv_diff = diff(cv);
cv_diff_angle = angle(cv_diff)*180/pi
cv_diff_angle =

  -71.56505
  -45.00000
  -63.43495
   26.56505
    0.00000
    0.00000
  -14.03624
    0.00000
  -14.03624
  -14.03624
    0.00000
    0.00000
  -26.56505
    0.00000
```

Manually checking this against a scatter plot of your data, this appears to be correct. Note that I multiplied by `180/pi` to get the angle in degrees.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!